# Data warehouse design - how to design for measures that are time related, such as last 7 days, etc

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm working rearchitecting a reporting/data warehouse type database.  We currently have a table that has data at the hotel grain (i.e. HotelID plus lots of measures, including measures like Last7DaysGross, Last28DaysXXX, etc).

I'm thinking that it would be best to move to a fact table that is at the Hotel/StayDate grain.  However, grouping on the HotelID and including date related measures such as Last7DaysGross need to perform very well.

What kind of structures would work here?  I don't think I'd be able to use indexed views the way that I had hoped, because of the multiple restrictions on them (no subqueries, etc.)  To have reasonable performance, will I need to create a new table at the Hotel level (aggregated from the HotelStayDate level?)  That's the level at which people will most often be querying.  Do I need to actually create fields such as Last7DaysGross?  That doesn't seem like a good design, but I'm having a hard time coming up with another one.

Sorry this question is a little vague.  Is there something else I'm missing here?  I know most often these kind date related measures would be done at the front-end level (i.e. in a tool such as Business Objects).  However, for this project, we'll need to have it in the database.

thanks,
Sylvia

EDIT:

Thanks for all the thoughtful comments! I accepted David Marwick answer because of his idea of having an expanded date dimension. That thought hadn't even crossed my mind, and it sounds well worth trying.

Expanding a little on David Marwick's thoughts, I came up with this idea.  I might try and see how it actually works:

```
DateDimension
   DateKey
   DateKeyBeginLast28Days
   DateKeyEndLast28Days

Fact
   DateKey
   GrossTransactions
```

Then when querying:

```
Select
   DateKey
   ,SumLast28Day = sum(GrossTransaction)
from Fact
   join DateDimension
      on Fact.DateKey >= DateDimension.DateKeyBeginLast28Days
      and Fact.DateKey <= DateDimension.DateKeyEndLast28Days
group by DateKey
```

Comment: How many transactions do you expect per day? IN total, over all hotels, down to grain of a single transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design of having one table at the [Hotel, Date] grain then rolling up into Hotel sounds fine. As Damir points out it keeps your read queries simple and makes it easy to add/remove aggregate measures going forward (keeping in mind that it's generally a bad idea to design around requirements that you *may* have in the future).

Pondlife makes good points as well. Your qualitative requirements might dictate how feasible it is to maintain an aggregate table, for example how often the system needs to update (daily, hourly, 15 mins, realtime?), how accurate the measures need to be (maybe the users just need a rough sense of how well each hotel is doing), how costly it is to read the source transaction data, how available the source transaction data is in the long-term (does it get archived), etc.

If you choose to add a [Hotel, StayDate] grain fact table and not maintain an aggregate then perhaps you can explore some tricks in your dimensions to save time. Maybe something like a 7-day date dimension containing [date, date_in_last_7_days] (so 7 records for each date) in case a straight join vs range querying the past 7 days saves you any time. That might be a stupid example but something along those lines. Date dimensions are small.

Lastly consider hardware optimizations like moving tables into memory (especially dimensions or non-gigantic fact tables) if you need to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate fact tables are entirely acceptable within Data Warehouses.

If you have not allready I would recommend the below book

[DW Toolkit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/0471200247)

In here Kimball states that the pre-aggregation of Fact tables into Aggregate fact tables is fine, however it does state they should be similar to the "base" fact table at a rolled up level.

The introduction of reporting fields I suspect should be in your front end Report tool or Cube viewer.

Comment: Thanks David.  I don't have a problem with aggregating to the Hotel level.  What doesn't seem right to me is aggregating the date-related measures (i.e. Last7DaysGross, etc).

Comment: My understanding is this should be done in the presentation layer. However if this is impossible, you could consider creating views on top of these tables to then base your reports on?

Comment: Would agree with David here. Your aggregation needs fit nicely with the OLAP cube concept.  these are mostly (not always) built and managed by the presentation layer i.e. tools like MicroStrategy, BO etc..

If thats not possible, live with some restrictions, and have fixed aggregate measures, 1 day, 7 day, 14 day, 30 day sum etc.  Aggregating on date level is not that bad, and is required for quite a few situations.

Answer (score 1):

As David says, there is nothing at all wrong with pre-aggregating some totals (during the ETL process) in order to make important queries run faster. This is a common technique even in operational databases and it makes a lot of sense in data warehouses if you know that certain aggregates are frequently used.

So you could certainly create a table called `FactHotelRevenueSummary` (or whatever matches your existing naming convention) with `HotelID, Last7DaysGross, Last28DaysGross` and as many other aggregates as you like.

The main points to consider first in my opinion are:

- Pre-aggregation is really necessary due to observable performance issues, i.e. you are adding complexity to the database in order to solve a real problem and not because you have a vague feeling that it might be helpful
- Your ETL process has checks to ensure that the aggregated data matches the 'raw' data exactly, otherwise you will get different numbers depending on which fact table you query and that has a very negative effect on user confidence

Answer (score 0):

Well depends, a usual query (for last 7 days) would look something like

```
select
    HotelName
  , sum(SaleAmount) as Sales
from factSale as s
join dimDate  as d on d.DateKey  = s.DateKey
join dimHotel as h on h.HotelKey = s.HotelKey 
where DaysAgo between 1 and 7
group by HotelName 
;
```

However, suppose you have a report which includes running sums (over periods) and their changes.
The report layout may look something like this:

```
| Date | 1-Day | Change-1-Day % | 7-Day | Change-7-Day % | 28-Day | Change-28-Day | 90-Day | Change-90-day % |
```

Not so simple any more. So, it is much easier to crate an aggregated (fact) table 
with pre-calculated fields for standard periods and run a query over that one.

So the aggregate (fact) table may look something like

```
factRunningSum
----------------------------
DateKey     integer  (PK)
HotelKey    integer  (PK)
Sale_1_Day  decimal(19,2)
Sale_7_Day  decimal(19,2)
Sale_28_Day decimal(19,2)
Sale_90_Day decimal(19,2)
```